# Retrieve query string data from external form

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have a page on my site that is used for registration at another site. The other site has given me a url to submit a form to. I am using an aspnetForm with the following .attr("method", "GET").attr("target", "_blank")... and some other code. Once the form is submitted to their site, the new blank window is filled with a message, saying whether or not the form submission was successful. The new page, which has the url from the other web site, contains a query string with data that would be useful to me, so that my application actually knows if the submission was successful, instead of just a visual cue to the user. Is there a way for my application to retrieve the query string data from this other window?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into using window.open, to send the data to the other site in a GET request?  With that, you can store a reference to the opened window in your own page, then access that window's DOM when needed.

Comment: I have since looked into that. I am still struggling to get a handle on the other window though. I get a null value when I try to reference window.open. Does the window being from another site affect the ability for me to get a reference? I found something about unchecking the 'Enable Protected Mode' setting in IE, which allowed me to get an object reference, but I don't think unchecking that is a very good solution. I was also looking into window.postMessage, but haven't figured out how I could utilize that.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that you are correct, and if you were allowed access to the other site like that, it would be a security risk (cross-site scripting / XSS).  I am not an expert on XSS, but I think you'd have to work with the owner of the other site if you wanted that kind of access.  Turning off default security settings for IE sounds risky, so I'm with you on that.  Maybe someone else can add some input to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Say if the returned URL you get is `https://other-site.apsx?usefulData=blah`

You can grab this from code behind by using:

```
var queryString = Request.QueryString["usefulData"];
```

This will give you the value of `usefuleData` which is `blah`.

Comment: The request and response is all done through javascript, so there isn't really a call back to the server code during this process. Is there a recommended way to get the two (Javascript and .Net) to talk to each other once the response in the new window is received?